# Python Datetime into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, csv, datetime

I'm parsing several years worth of daily solar generation CSV files that look like this (with YY-MM-DD.CSV filename format)

```
sep=;
Version CSV|Tool SunnyBeam11|Linebreaks CR/LF|Delimiter semicolon|Decimalpoint point|Precision 3|Language en-UK|TZO=0|DST|11/03/2012

    ;SN: xyz
    ;SB blah
    ;xyz
    Time;Power
    HH:mm;kW
    00:10;0.000
    00:20;0.000
    00:30;0.000
    00:40;0.000
    00:50;0.000
    01:00;0.000
    01:10;0.000
    01:20;0.000
    01:30;0.000
    01:40;0.000
    01:50;0.000
    02:00;0.000
    02:10;0.000
    02:20;0.000
    02:30;0.000
    02:40;0.000
    02:50;0.000
    03:00;0.000
    03:10;0.000
    03:20;0.000
    03:30;0.000
    03:40;0.000
    03:50;0.000
    04:00;0.000
    04:10;0.000
    04:20;0.000
    04:30;0.000
    04:40;0.000
    04:50;0.000
    05:00;0.000
    05:10;0.000
    05:20;0.000
    05:30;0.000
    05:40;0.000
    05:50;0.000
    06:00;0.000
    06:10;0.000
    06:20;0.000
    06:30;0.000
    06:40;0.000
    06:50;0.000
    07:00;0.000
    07:10;0.012
    07:20;0.048
    07:30;0.072
    07:40;0.078
    07:50;0.114
    08:00;0.150
    08:10;0.156
    08:20;0.168
    08:30;0.204
    08:40;0.180
    08:50;0.198
    09:00;0.210
    09:10;0.222
    09:20;0.294
    09:30;0.330
    09:40;0.342
    09:50;0.402
    10:00;0.492
    10:10;0.396
    10:20;0.474
    10:30;1.224
    10:40;1.374
    10:50;1.416
    11:00;1.470
    11:10;1.500
    11:20;1.530
    11:30;1.530
    11:40;1.542
    11:50;1.536
    12:00;1.554
    12:10;1.584
    12:20;1.584
    12:30;1.572
    12:40;1.560
    12:50;1.548
    13:00;1.518
    13:10;1.494
    13:20;1.470
    13:30;1.440
    13:40;1.404
    13:50;1.356
    14:00;1.332
    14:10;1.284
    14:20;1.236
    14:30;1.194
    14:40;1.110
    14:50;1.050
    15:00;0.972
    15:10;0.888
    15:20;0.816
    15:30;0.744
    15:40;0.648
    15:50;0.594
    16:00;0.528
    16:10;0.438
    16:20;0.342
    16:30;0.264
    16:40;0.228
    16:50;0.180
    17:00;0.120
    17:10;0.084
    17:20;0.048
    17:30;0.024
    17:40;0.006
    17:50;0.000
    18:00;0.000
    18:10;0.000
    18:20;0.000
    18:30;0.000
    18:40;0.000
    18:50;0.000
    19:00;0.000
    19:10;0.000
    19:20;0.000
    19:30;0.000
    19:40;0.000
    19:50;0.000
    20:00;0.000
    20:10;0.000
    20:20;0.000
    20:30;0.000
    20:40;0.000
    20:50;0.000
    21:00;0.000
    21:10;0.000
    21:20;0.000
    21:30;0.000
    21:40;0.000
    21:50;0.000
    22:00;0.000
    22:10;0.000
    22:20;0.000
    22:30;0.000
    22:40;0.000
    22:50;0.000
    23:00;0.000
    23:10;0.000
    23:20;0.000
    23:30;0.000
    23:40;0.000
    23:50;0.000
    00:00;0.000


    E-Today kWh;8.313
    E-Total kWh;67.471
```

My Python is able to parse out the date in the last field of line 2 and then iteratively combine it with the time on each row. Using the combo of date and time as a timestamp (type incompatibility is probably the problem?) I try to insert it into a mySQL database into a column of type timestamp (and power into a column of type DECIMAL(4,3))

I've played around with various type combinations but clearly not in the right way. I'd be really grateful for a Python expert to clarify how to successfully get the synthesised date into a form compatible with MySQL timestamp.

The Python is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from os import listdir
from datetime import datetime
import MySQLdb
#from sys import argv


def is_dated_csv(filename):
    """
    Return True if filename matches format YY-MM-DD.csv, otherwise False.
    """
    date_format = '%y-%m-%d.csv'

    try:
        date = datetime.strptime(filename, date_format)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        # filename did not match pattern
        print filename + ' did NOT match'
        pass
#'return' terminates a function
    return False


def parse_for_date(filename):
  """
  Read file for the date - from line 2 field 10
  """
  currentFile = open(filename,'r')
  l1 = currentFile.readline() #ignore first line read
  date_line = currentFile.readline() #read second line
  dateLineArray = date_line.split("|")
  day_in_question = dateLineArray[-1]#save the last element (date)
  currentFile.close()
  return day_in_question


def normalise_date_to_UTF(day_in_question):
  """
  Rather wierdly, some days use YYYY.MM.DD format & others use DD/MM/YYYY
  This function normalises either to UTC with a blank time (midnight)
  """
  if '.' in day_in_question: #it's YYYY.MM.DD
    dateArray = day_in_question.split(".")
    dt = (dateArray[0] +dateArray[1] + dateArray[2].rstrip() + '000000')
  elif '/' in day_in_question: #it's DD/MM/YYYY
    dateArray = day_in_question.split("/")
    dt = (dateArray[2].rstrip() + dateArray[1] + dateArray[0] + '000000')
  theDate = datetime.strptime(dt,'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
  return theDate #A datetime object


def parse_power_values(filename, theDate):
  currentFile = open(filename,'r')
  for i, line in enumerate(currentFile):
    if i <= 7:
      doingSomething = True
      #print 'header' + str(i) + '/ ' + line.rstrip()
    elif ((i > 7) and (i <= 151)):
      lineParts = line.split(';')
      theTime = lineParts[0].split(':')
      theHour = theTime[0]
      theMin = theTime[1]
      timestamp = theDate.replace(hour=int(theHour),minute=int(theMin))
      power = lineParts[1].rstrip()
      if (float(power) > 0):
        #print str(i) + '/ ' + str(timestamp) + '   power = ' + power + 'kWh'
        append_to_database(timestamp,power)
      #else:
      #  print str(i) + '/ '
    elif i > 151:
      print str(timestamp) + ' DONE!'
      print '----------------------'
      break
  currentFile.close()

def append_to_database(timestampval,powerval):
  a = datetime.strptime(timestampval,"%b %d %Y %H:%M")
  host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
  user="root", # your username
  passwd="******"
  database_name = 'SunnyData'
  table_name = 'DTP'
  timestamp_column  = 'DT'
  power_column = 'PWR'
  sql = ("""INSERT INTO %s(%s,%s) VALUES(%s,'%s')""", ('table_name', 'timestamp_column', 'power_column', a.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), powerval) )
  print sql
  #db = MySQLdb.connect(host,user,passwd,database_name)
  cur = SD.cursor()
  try:
    cur.execute(sql)
    print 'SQL: ' + sql
    SD.commit()
  except:
    print 'DB append failed!'
    SD.rollback()

# Main start of program
path = '.'
for filename in listdir(path):
    if is_dated_csv(filename):
        SD = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root",passwd="**********", db = 'SunnyData')
        print filename + ' matched'
      # Do something with the desired .csv file
        day_in_question = parse_for_date(filename)
        print 'the date is ' + day_in_question
        theDate = normalise_date_to_UTF(day_in_question)
        parse_power_values(filename, theDate)
        SD.close()

    pass
```

and the DB create SQL looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE `DTP` (
  `idDTP` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DT` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `PWR` decimal(4,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDTP`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Many thanks,

Greg (Python novice)

Comment: Thats a lot of code you want people to look through. Please consider shortening it to an MCVE. Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: The longest section is just a data file, showing what's parsed and I suspect I could show just the section of Python where I suspect the problem is (def append_to_database() function) but TBH it may not be there, so I left it all. Finally, I wanted to make sure it's not the Schema that's the problem, so I included a short SQL create. Hope that's OK. I'll bear the sentiment in mind for next time :o)

Comment: When you print does it display in the proper format you expect that MySQL requires for the TIMESTAMP? Have you tried using DATETIME instead? There are some subtleties that could be the issue

Comment: What does your insert SQL look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your code, and it seems like the main issues are in the `append_to_database` function.

It looks like the return value of  `normalise_date_to_UTF` returns a datetime object, which is being passed to `append_to_database` (as the `timestampval` argument), and that is being run through [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), which is unnecessary since it's not a string and already a datetime.

The SQL statement also needed some adjusting for how you replace variables in strings. In python, the `%` operator when following a string, allows you to insert values into that string via format codes. Also, `table_name`, `timestamp_column`, and `power_column` had single quotes around them, which meant that the literal string would be inserted, rather than the variable's value.

Basically your `append_to_database` function should look like this:

```
def append_to_database(timestampval,powerval):
  host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
  user="root", # your username
  passwd="******"
  database_name = 'SunnyData'
  table_name = 'DTP'
  timestamp_column  = 'DT'
  power_column = 'PWR'
  sql = ("INSERT INTO %s (%s,%s) VALUES('%s','%s')" % (table_name, timestamp_column, power_column, timestampval.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), powerval) )
  print sql
  #db = MySQLdb.connect(host,user,passwd,database_name)
  cur = SD.cursor()
  try:
    cur.execute(sql)
    print 'SQL: ' + sql
    SD.commit()
  except:
    print 'DB append failed!'
    SD.rollback()
```

As for the MySQL DB, the SQL inserts are not specifying a value for the `idDTP` column, and the column isn't auto incrementing, so after python inserts the first value, all subsequent inserts will fail, because the value defaults to 0 for each insert. This can be resolved in one of two ways, altering the python code to specify a value for `idDTP` or setting idDTP to be auto incrementing.

If you want to alter your table to have auto incrementing ids, the SQL syntax (run on the MySQL server) is:

```
ALTER TABLE DTP MODIFY COLUMN idDTP INT auto_increment
```

or you can recreate the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `DTP` (
  `idDTP` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DT` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `PWR` decimal(4,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDTP`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I ran your code, making the changes above, and with the first part of the data provided, when querying MySQL for the DTP table, it looks like this:

```
select * from DTP;
+-------+---------------------+-------+
| idDTP | DT                  | PWR   |
+-------+---------------------+-------+
|     1 | 2012-03-11 07:10:00 | 0.012 |
|     2 | 2012-03-11 07:20:00 | 0.048 |
|     3 | 2012-03-11 07:30:00 | 0.072 |
|     4 | 2012-03-11 07:40:00 | 0.078 |
|     5 | 2012-03-11 07:50:00 | 0.114 |
|     6 | 2012-03-11 08:00:00 | 0.150 |
|     7 | 2012-03-11 08:10:00 | 0.156 |
|     8 | 2012-03-11 08:20:00 | 0.168 |
|     9 | 2012-03-11 08:30:00 | 0.204 |
|    10 | 2012-03-11 08:40:00 | 0.180 |
+-------+---------------------+-------+
```

Hope that helps you with this project!